# How can i pass callback as argument to function and execute it from c++ side?

Tags: javascript, v8, embedded-v8

When i embedded chakracore i could get argument which contains passed callback and execute this function with my own passed arguments to callback. How can i do it in v8 engine?

js example
`readFile("C:/test.txt", (data, err) => {console.log(data, err)})`

I tried to google this problem but didn't find answers.

Answer (score 0):

`v8::Function` has a `Call(...)` method.

See the [V8 samples](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/main/samples) for various examples how to use the V8 API.